# Button Click Moves Entire HTML Body

Tags: jquery, html, css, button, drop-down-menu

I have a very basic webpage-setup that includes a drop-down menu that is triggered by a button click.  When I click on the button, the drop-down menu reveals itself but also shifts the entire contents of that page.  I'm not sure what is causing this and would appreciate any help.  Thank you in advance!

Here is a live link:  http://copy-writer-shipments-14524.bitballoon.com/

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ManaBadi</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css">
    <script src="./jquery_min.js"></script>
    <script src="./button_dropdown_menu.js"></script>
    <script src="./nav_hide_show.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main_content_container">
    <header>
    <span>ManaBadi</span>
    <img src="./menu100.png" id="hamburger_menu_icon" alt="menu icon">
        <ul id="nav_ul">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Goal</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Class Schedule</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ManaBadi Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Photo Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Video Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <div id="media_scroll">
        <div id="scrolling_text">
            <p>ManaBadi Admissions Open for 2015-2016 Academic Year.  To Open ManaBadi New Location Contact sarath@siliconandhra.org or Call 203 583 9537</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h3>Locations</h3>
<div>
    <ul id="button_ul">
        <li>
            <button id="select_region_button"><p>Select Region</p></button>
            <ul class="dropdown_menu" id="region_dropdown_menu">
                <li class="region_locations">Select Region</li>
                <li class="region_locations"><a href="#">USA South-West</a></li>
                <li class="region_locations"><a href="#">USA Mid-West</a></li>
                <li class="region_locations"><a href="#">USA South-East</a></li>
                <li class="region_locations"><a href="#">USA North-East</a></li>
                <li class="region_locations"><a href="#">USA West</a></li>
                <li class="region_locations"><a href="#">Hong Kong</a></li>
                <li class="region_locations"><a href="#">UK</a></li>
                <li class="region_locations"><a href="#">Canada</a></li>
                <li class="region_locations"><a href="#">Kuwait</a></li>
                <li class="region_locations"><a href="#">Norway</a></li>
                <li class="region_locations"><a href="#">Singapore</a></li>
                <li class="region_locations"><a href="#">New Zealand</a></li>
                <li class="region_locations"><a href="#">Malaysia</a></li>
                <li class="region_locations"><a href="#">Austrailia</a></li>
                <li class="region_locations"><a href="#">Dubai</a></li>
                <li class="region_locations"><a href="#">Scotland</a></li>
                <li class="region_locations"><a href="#">Nigeria</a></li>
                <li class="region_locations"><a href="#">South Africa</a></li>
                <li class="region_locations"><a href="#">Netherlands</a></li>
                <li class="region_locations"><a href="#">Switzerland</a></li>
                <li class="region_locations"><a href="#">Kingdom of Saudi Arabia</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button id="select_state_button"><p>Select State</p></button>
            <ul class="dropdown_menu" id="state_dropdown_menu">
                <li class="state_locations">Select State</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button id="select_city_button"><p>Select City</p></button>
            <ul class="dropdown_menu" id="city_dropdown_menu">
                <li class="city_locations">Select City</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button>GO</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="school_info_container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS:

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (pub.*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}

body {
    line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/*=============================RESET=================================*/

body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#main_content_container {
    width: 80%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 5%;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px lightgrey;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px lightgrey;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px lightgrey;
    -ms-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px lightgrey;
    -o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px lightgrey;
}

span {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 3em;
    top: 15px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 201px;
    height: 45px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

#nav_ul {
    width: 58%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#nav_ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 1em;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#nav_ul li:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}

#nav_ul li:nth-child(10) {
    border-right: none;
}

#button_ul {
    width: auto;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

#button_ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

#region_dropdown_menu li, #state_dropdown_menu li, #city_dropdown_menu li {
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    padding: 2px 0;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

a:visited {
    color: blue;
}

#hamburger_menu_icon {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 15px;
}

#hamburger_menu_icon:hover {
    /*background-color: #66D9EF;*/
    background-color: yellow;
}

#media_scroll {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1390px) {
    #main_content_container {
        margin-top: 6%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
    #main_content_container {
        margin-top: 7%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 975px) {
    #main_content_container {
        margin-top: 8%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 845px) {
    #main_content_container {
        margin-top: 9%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 740px) {
    #main_content_container {
        margin-top: 12%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 555px) {
    #main_content_container {
        margin-top: 14%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 475px) {
    #main_content_container {
        margin-top: 16%;
    }


@media screen and (max-width: 416px) {
    #main_content_container {
        margin-top: 19%;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is better if you show something in the live. The code you have provided gives only a basic information. Can you show something in live, like a fiddle? You can add a fiddle by pressing `Ctrl + M`.

Comment: Please only give relevant code and a jsfiddle to show us the problem. if I just copy-paste your code in a jsfiddle, I can't reproduce the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/wj1d01k1/

Comment: This feels like the submenus aren't positioned absolutely.

Comment: @PraveenKumar thank you for the suggestion.  I just added a live link that shows the problem I'm experiencing!

Comment: @dannyk Works well for me... No problem. `:/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres your problem: **Your menu exists**.

I know, that sounds snarky, but it's true. Because you element that contains the menu is inline and *is there*, as soon as you expand it it will push content down. A quick fix for that is to position it something different than `relative` - as `relative` will place it *relative* to other, surrounding, content. Try `position: absolute`. It doesn't look great as you'll have to style it differently this way (give it a background etc...). Usually people use `position: fixed;` for this to place it relative to the viewport.

Here a quick example, just click the buttons to switch the positioning from `relative` to position `absolute` and use the 'show' button to see what a little animation does to show a a difference which what content pushes and which doesn't:

```js
$("#switch").click(function(){ $("#menu").toggleClass("absolute"); });
$("#show").click(function(){ $("#menu").toggleClass("show"); });
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body > div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  background: red;
}
body #content { background: yellow; }
body #menu {
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: height 500ms;
  transition: height 500ms;
  background: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
body #menu.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
body #menu.show {
  height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="header"></div>
<div id="menu">My Menu</div>
<div id="content"></div>

<br />
<input type="button" value="show" id="show" />
<input type="button" value="Switch relative with absolute" id="switch" />
```

Be careful with this however, as elements positioned `absolute` are positioned so from the closest parent that has positioning set itself. So if you make your wrapper `relative`, you menu will position from the top left of your wrapper and not your page (although this might be the result your are looking for). To fix it in accordance to the viewport, use `fixed`. `fixed` is (barely) influenced by other wrapping elements (unless you forgot to set a two positioning coordinates like `top` or `left`).

Answer (score -1):

Add `position:absolute` to the css for `.dropdown_menu` and it will stop the menu pushing the content of the page down.

Comment: OP means that elements get moved, not that the page is scrolled.